# No List matches the given query

Tags: python, html, django, django-models, comments

I want to be able to add a comment on the product page, but after clicking on the comment button, it gives this error. What is the problem?
I tried this code before, it worked perfectly, but now it gives an error.

views.py

```
def item_detail(request, item_bid_id):
    get_item = get_object_or_404(List, pk=item_bid_id)
    get_item_2 = get_item.first_bid
    filter_item = Bidmodel.objects.filter(listb_id = item_bid_id)
    comment = Comments.objects.filter(listc_id = item_bid_id)
    
    context = {
        'item' : get_item,
        'now_bid': auxiliary(get_item_2, filter_item),
        'comments' : comment,
        }
    
    return render(request, 'auctions/item_detail.html', context )



# comment
@login_required(login_url="login")
def comments(request):
    comment = request.GET["comment"]
    username = request.user.username
    list_id = request.POST.get("listid", False)
    newcomment = Comments(user = username, comment = comment, listc_id = list_id)
    newcomment.save()
    return item_detail(request, list_id)`
```

item_detail.html:

```
`{% extends "auctions/layout.html" %}

{% block body %}
    {% if messages %}
        {% for message in messages %}
            <div>{{ message }}</div>
        {% endfor %}
    {% endif %}
    
    <img src= {{ item.image.url }} alt = "{{item.title}}"><br>
    <a><a>Product:</a>{{ item.title }}</a><br>
    <a><a>Category: </a>{{ item.category }}</a><br>
    <a><a>Desc: </a>{{ item.description }}</a><br>
    <a><a>Status: </a>{{ item.status }}</a><br>
    <a><a>Frist Bid: </a> {{ item.first_bid }} $ </a><br>
    <div><a><a>Current Bid: </a> {{ now_bid }} $ </div>
    <div><a><a>Listed By: </a> {{ item.user }}</div>
    


    <h3 id="h3">Comments</h3>
    <div>
        <ul>
            {% for comment in comments %}
                <li><a><a>{{ comment.user }} : {{comment.comment}}</a></li>
            {% endfor %}
        </ul>
    </div>

    <form method = "get" action ="{% url "comments" %}">
        <input required type = "text" placeholder = "Add Comment" name = "comment">
        <button type = "submit" value = {{ list.id }} name = "listid"> Comment </button>
    </form>
   
{% endblock%}
```

And the table related to the comment has also been created.

This is an error that comes:

Page not found (404)

No List matches the given query.

Request Method:GET

Request URLhttp://127.0.0.1:8000/comments?comment=good

Raised by:  auctions.views.comments

Using the URLconf defined in commerce.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:

```
admin/

[name='index']

login [name='login']

logout [name='logout']

register [name='register']

auctions/<int:item_bid_id>
 [name='item_detail'] 
auxiliary [name='auxiliary']

comments [name='comments']
```

The current path, comments, matched the last one.

Comment: You have a couple of typos in the template where you need to use double and single quotes: `<form method = "get" action ="{% url 'comments' %}">`, and then you need quotes here: `<button type = "submit" value = '{{ list.id }}' name = "listid"> Comment </button>`

Comment: Can you post the error message

Comment: Share the *full* traceback.

Comment: @raphael Hi, I applied the changes you said, but it didn't make a difference and it still gives the same error.

Comment: Can you clarify what is `List` in `get_item = get_object_or_404(List, pk=item_bid_id)`

Comment: @ raphael This model is for items.

Comment: You are trying to recieve a `POST` with `list_id = request.POST.get("listid", False)`, but are actually sending a `GET` request, so try changing it to `list_id = request.GET.get("listid", False)`.  And since `listid` is probably a number, the default should not be set to `FALSE`, so maybe just do `list_id = request.POST.get("listid")` and then check if `list_id` is `None`.

Comment: It the `comments` view, shouldn't you be returning a `redirect` instead of a `view function`? 

Try `return redirect("item-detail", kwargs={"item_bid_id": list_id})`.

Comment: @ McPherson it send this error:NoReverseMatch at /comments
Reverse for 'item_detail' with keyword arguments '{'kwargs': {'item_bid_id': False}}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['auctions/(?P<item_bid_id>[0-9]+)\\Z']

Comment: @ raphael it send this error again:Page not found (404)
No List matches the given query.